# In Ionic or cordova platform, how to sync and retrieve database from iCloud

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, synchronization, icloud

I have build an app using ionic framework, and the data uses sqlite database and stores in app /documents folder.

Now I want to know is it possible to sync the database into iCloud, so the user can retrieve the data automatically if they reinstall the app or use a new device.

I did search for some solution, some suggest sync to remote database using such as pouchDB or parse. But as for our company policy, we cannot store app data into any other remote place exclude iCloud.

Any ideas? Thank you so much.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue as well

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, iCloud automatically backs up data on the user's local storage. You don't need to do anything extra.

I might be wrong, but soome people seem to have [problems with it doing that](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/istore-rejects-app-for-storing-content-on-icloud/45990/3)

Check out [this page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/)

Relevant:

```
BackupWebStorage(string) 
Default: cloud 
Allowed values: none, local, cloud. 
Set to cloud to allow web storage data to backup via iCloud. Set to local to allow only local backups via iTunes sync. Set to none prevent web storage backups.
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I did use local storage in previous version, but the problem for local storage is iOS will randomly clear the local storage when the iPhone memory is low. Therefore, I turned to use sqlite database to store all data. I am sure this database can be backup via iCloud. But My question is I want the app can snyc the data real time between different devices which are connected to same iCloud account just like the note app in iPhone.

Comment: And in my understanding, we have to restore everything if we want to restore from iCloud backup. That is not I want ideally as well... The perfect scenario is that the user delete the app, and reinstall it through app store, the whole data will back again. I am not sure if it is possible